# Restarting GSM Modem from app if unresponsive

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am building an app to send `SMS` using GSM Modem. Currently, I am using **ZTE NMEA** and **Huawei E1550** GSM Modem, and sometimes both of them become unresponsive i.e. cannot seem to send SMS, and I have to plug it out from USB and plug back in.

But in production environment this will not be acceptable. I am looking a way to solve this from my app but could not find a way.

I am using `C#.net`. If anyone have gone through same problem or have any idea to solve this problem via app, I do expect `C#` classes or code or methodology to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a straight SUB cable to connect to the modem or does the cable have convert to a D-Connector (9, or 25 pin)?  I think the serial port hardware/controls controls may be set.  You should be not be using hardware controls nor software controls in your serial port settings.

Comment: I am connecting it to USB Port, if sorry I said Serial Port, it is actually listed inside COM Port on device manager.

Comment: I found some C++ code on webpage below.   You can get the equivalent C# commands from www.pinvoke.net  : http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?418183-Reset-USB-connection